# How to Freez Title in scrollView when title is not showing on display while scrolling?

Tags: android, scrollview, freeze

I want to Display Title textView with title text in scrollview while I am scroll down and that title is not in screen. I mean it is scrolled up. Basically I want to freez title on top of the screen when I am scrolling down and title goes up and not visible for user because of it scroll up. Here is My XMl file. 
I want to freeze TextView whose id="@+id/freezed_title_text" when
TextView whose id="@+id/title_text" is scroll up and not visible in screen.
Thank you in Advance....

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/freezed_title_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="@color/news_detail_text_textcolor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/hdpi_news_detail_title_textsize"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroolview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/exp_background"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/freezed_title_text">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_layout_height" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temp_title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_marginright"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/news_detail_text_textcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hdpi_news_detail_title_textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_layout_height"
            android:layout_below="@+id/temp_title_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/news_detail_margintop" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/largeimage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/loadrefresh1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/like_dislike_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/news_detail_linear_marginbottom"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_linear_marginright" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/like"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutwidth"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutheight"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutmarginright"
                    android:src="@drawable/like_bigger" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dislike"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutwidth"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutheight"
                    android:src="@drawable/disklike_bigger" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relParent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_marginright"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_margintop"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/messageButton"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutwidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutheight"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutmarginleft"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/facebookButton"
                android:src="@drawable/message_bigger" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutwidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutheight"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutmarginleft"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/twitterButton"
                android:src="@drawable/facebook_bigger" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/twitterButton"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutwidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutheight"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutmarginleft"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linkedinButton"
                android:src="@drawable/twiter_bigger" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/linkedinButton"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutwidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutheight"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_img_marginleft"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_img_marginright"
                android:src="@drawable/linkden_bigger" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relParent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_marginright"
            android:textColor="@color/news_detail_text_textcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hdpi_news_detail_title_textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/EMPTY"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_text_layout_height"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title_text"
            android:textColor="@color/newsview_text_colro" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/datailtext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/EMPTY"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginright"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/news_detail_text_margintop"
            android:text="@string/detailed_text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/news_detail_text_textcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hdpi_news_detail_text_textsize" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/datailtext"
            android:background="@color/exp_background"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="250sp"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:background="@color/exp_background" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/keyword_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginright"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/keyword_layout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginright"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/l1"
                android:layout_width="130sp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:background="#6f6f6f" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/black_dot"
                android:layout_width="11dp"
                android:layout_height="11dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutmarginleft"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutmarginleft"
                android:background="@drawable/round_dot"
                android:textColor="@color/newsview_text_colro" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/l2"
                android:layout_width="130sp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:background="#6f6f6f" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_related_news"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line_2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginright"
            android:background="#1f1f21"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:text="Related News"
            android:textColor="#d1d1d3"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/related_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_related_news"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginright"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/urlTextBottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/related_container"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginright"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="asvcagvcgavscjhasjahvjvsachv"
            android:textColor="@color/news_detail_text_textcolor"
            android:textColorLink="@color/news_detail_text_textcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hdpi_news_detail_text_textsize" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: add an image of what you want to achieve and what is your current code?? Post it here

Comment: Now XML code and Desire Output Image is also attached So plz help me to solve my Issue

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a linearlayout with title and scrollview:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/freezed_title_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="@color/news_detail_text_textcolor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/hdpi_news_detail_title_textsize"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:visibility="gone"/>


  <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/freezed_title_text"
     android:orientation="vertical">
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temp_title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_marginright"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/news_detail_text_textcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hdpi_news_detail_title_textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold"  />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroolview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/exp_background"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_layout_height" >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_layout_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/news_detail_margintop" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/largeimage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/loadrefresh1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/like_dislike_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/news_detail_linear_marginbottom"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_linear_marginright" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/like"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutwidth"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutheight"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutmarginright"
                    android:src="@drawable/like_bigger" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dislike"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutwidth"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutheight"
                    android:src="@drawable/disklike_bigger" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relParent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_marginright"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_margintop"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/messageButton"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutwidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutheight"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutmarginleft"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/facebookButton"
                android:src="@drawable/message_bigger" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutwidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutheight"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutmarginleft"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/twitterButton"
                android:src="@drawable/facebook_bigger" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/twitterButton"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutwidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutheight"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutmarginleft"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linkedinButton"
                android:src="@drawable/twiter_bigger" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/linkedinButton"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutwidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutheight"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_img_marginleft"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_img_marginright"
                android:src="@drawable/linkden_bigger" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relParent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_rellayout_marginright"
            android:textColor="@color/news_detail_text_textcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hdpi_news_detail_title_textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/EMPTY"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/news_detail_text_layout_height"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title_text"
            android:textColor="@color/newsview_text_colro" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/datailtext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/EMPTY"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginright"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/news_detail_text_margintop"
            android:text="@string/detailed_text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/news_detail_text_textcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hdpi_news_detail_text_textsize" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/datailtext"
            android:background="@color/exp_background"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="250sp"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:background="@color/exp_background" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/keyword_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginright"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/keyword_layout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginright"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/l1"
                android:layout_width="130sp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:background="#6f6f6f" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/black_dot"
                android:layout_width="11dp"
                android:layout_height="11dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutmarginleft"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_img_layoutmarginleft"
                android:background="@drawable/round_dot"
                android:textColor="@color/newsview_text_colro" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/l2"
                android:layout_width="130sp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:background="#6f6f6f" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_related_news"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line_2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginright"
            android:background="#1f1f21"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:text="Related News"
            android:textColor="#d1d1d3"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/related_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_related_news"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginright"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/urlTextBottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/related_container"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_detail_text_marginright"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="asvcagvcgavscjhasjahvjvsachv"
            android:textColor="@color/news_detail_text_textcolor"
            android:textColorLink="@color/news_detail_text_textcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hdpi_news_detail_text_textsize" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```